# Questions about my binary planet system

Tags: physics, astronomy, solar-system, tectonics, tidal-forces

I’ve recently designed a star system containing a habitable double planetary system, but I still have several questions to fill in I need answered.

My binary planet is a Venus sized (mostly) Earth-like planet, paired and tidally locked to a mars massed “super mercury” which orbit each other every 30 hours. the system as a whole resembles an earth-moon system slapped onto a Pluto-Charon template.

Before I make any surface maps, I really want to know how the tidal and centrifugal force affects the tectonic activity, the oceans,
And the weather patterns. I really want the planet to be accurate, but more importantly I wonder what interesting concepts could come from this setup. Will there be a sublunar mid-ocean ridge? Will the plates be able to stay large as the planets stretch and contract between apogee and perigee? Will the lunar gravity and centrifugal force affect, if not dominate convection patterns in the air? I have so much to fill in and no real idea on what to assume right off the bat

Below I have specifications of the system

Primary planet:

- Mass: 0.8 earth masses
- Diameter: 0.95 earth diameter
- Surface gravity: 0.85g

Secondary planet:

- Mass: 0.1 earth masses
- Diameter: ~0.3 earth diameter

Semi major axis: 47320 km
Period: 30 hours

---

---

Please feel free to add anything interesting you can extrapolate from this system, and the implications of these effects.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If the two planets are tidally locked then there are no tides, by definition.

Comment: @AlexP There will be tides  as they orbit their mutual center of gravity around the star.

Comment: You are asking a tall order here. Stack Exchange is fairly particular about how you ask a question. Just pretend you are asking and Evil DJinn for a wish. :)
Also, in your world information, you might want to provide your worlds age as that is crucial to some of the answers.

Comment: @Gillgamesh: The question literally says "tidally locked". This means that the only tides will be those produced by the star, for which the question provides no data.

Comment: I’ve reformatted the question and posted it here: Tectonic plates on a binary planet
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/231295/96671?sem=2

Comment: @Gillgamesh: Yes, you understand correctly. As I said, the only tides will be those due to the star (or sun, if you prefer). The question does not contain any data to say anything meaningful about them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's way, way, way, way, way too broad. From the [help/dont-ask] we read, "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." You want to know how *both* tidal and centrifugal forces affect (a) tectonic activity, (b) oceans, and (c) weather patterns. That's six questions - and any one of them is too broad (we don't understand all that for Earth).